# Why would typeof(T) kill performance?

Tags: c#, entity-system

**TLDR:** using `typeof(T)` twice; assigning the value to a variable and reusing that = uber fast (30FPS), actually calling `typeof(T)` twice = derped (5FPS). Why?

---

I have a simple entity/component system; my basic entity had an array of `IComponent`s, and methods like `HasComponent<T>` and `GetComponent<T>`. These just iterate over the arrays and return the first matching item (`this.components.Any(c => c is T)`).

Turns out a performance bottleneck I experience with 100k components "in memory" (albeit most off-screen) is actually these two methods. With a few components, no problem (30FPS+). With 100k components, just sprites, I get around 5FPS.

So I figured, why not use a `Dictionary<Type, IComponent>` instead? It'll be faster, right?

Right?!

Wrong. First, a complexity: I have a `SpriteComponent` class, and a `SpriteSheetComponent` component class (knows about frames, animation, etc.). To simplify everything, `SpriteSheetComponent` derives from `SpriteComponent`. This makes drawing, ordering, etc. simpler, because of the is-a relationship.

Second, querying for components became more complex; if I ask `HasComponent<SpriteComponent>`, and you have a `SpriteSheetComponent`, you should return `true`, right?

So the way I handle that is:

`return this.components.Keys.Any(t => t == typeof(T) || t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)));`

Ditto for fetching the element, except I use `First` instead of `Any`.

Anyway, I noticed that the performance actually **degraded**. What's even more surprising is that this fixed the performance issue:

```
var tType = typeof(T);
return this.components.Keys.Any(t => t == tType || t.IsSubclassOf(tType));
```

The only difference is that **I'm checking typeof(T) once and reusing *that*.** This fixed my FPS up to 30ish, hurrah.

But this is definitely a "lolwut" moment for me. Is `typeof(T)` really that slow? And in this case, it's shredding my performance with just *one extra call*?

Comment: This is probably more of a Stackoverflow question. In fact, I found an answer for it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417763/efficiency-of-cs-typeof-operator-or-whatever-its-representation-is-in-msil and dotnerperls also has a bit to say on it: http://www.dotnetperls.com/typeof How many of these comparisons are you doing per frame?

Comment: Honestly, I'd consider `typeof` to be a red flag function, you probably call it because you have made a mess of your data structure. If you had a clean design the type would either be implicit in the code, or the difference would be handled by the objects's own methods.

Comment: @eBusiness getting components by type from a generic container is, as far as I know, a standard solution to designing your entity system.

Comment: @ashes999 I recognize that you have been particularly unlucky, and even with the given explanations I fail to understand why `typeof` would be *that* slow. That you are paying in speed for using a generic container is however no surprise. The thing is, you are probably also paying in some combination of code complexity, readability, and debugability. The key question is, if you want to treat the objects differently, why do you put them on the same list in the first place?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, it's not really *one* extra call, is it?  It's n * 100k extra calls per frame, if you're doing this every time you retrieve the sprite component for each entity!

Maybe your entity should just have a field for the sprite component, null if it hasn't got one, rather than indirecting through all this dictionary and typeof stuff.  Ditto for other commonly used components.

I understand the impluse to generalize, but your system sounds rather overengineered for what it needs to do.

BTW, if you have 100k entities (a *huge* number by most game standards) and most of them are offscreen, you should *definitely* invest in a space-partitioning system of some sort so you can avoid updating - or even looping over - all of 'em.

Comment: I actually do have a spatial partitioning scheme already (quad tree). I'm selectively drawing what's on-screen *only*. The problem is, these are just map tiles -- I can't even keep a 100x100 map in memory and draw some of it on screen. Maybe pulling out the sprite component makes more sense.

Comment: I started adding straight sprite components instead of adding them as entities and the issues seems somewhat resolved. Cheers.